# Encode string as html in eXist-db / XQuery

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I'm trying to generate a treeview from a collection (filesystem). Unfortunately some Files have special characters like ü ä and ö. And I'd like to have them html encoded as `&­auml;`

When I get them from the variable, they are URL encoded. First I decode them to UTF-8 and then .... i don't know how to go further.

```
<li><a href="#">{util:unescape-uri($child, "UTF-8")}</a>
```

The function `util:parse` is doing the exact opposite from that what I want.

Here is the recursive function:

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace ls="ls";

declare option exist:serialize "method=html media-type=text/html omit-xml-declaration=yes indent=yes";

declare function ls:ls($collection as xs:string, $subPath as xs:string) as element()* {
  if (xmldb:collection-available($collection)) then
    (         
      for $child in xmldb:get-child-collections($collection)
      let $path := concat($collection, '/', $child) 
      let $sPath := concat($subPath, '/', $child)
      order by $child 
      return
        <li><a href="#">{util:unescape-uri($child, "UTF-8")}</a>
          <ul>
          {ls:ls($path,$sPath)}
          </ul>
        </li>,

        for $child in xmldb:get-child-resources($collection)
        let $sPath := concat($subPath, '/', $child)
        order by $child 
        return
            <li> <a href="javascript:loadPage('{$sPath}');">{util:unescape-uri($child, "UTF-8")}</a></li> 
    )
  else ()    
};  

let $collection := request:get-parameter('coll', '/db/apps/ebner-online/resources/xss/xml')
return
  <ul>{ls:ls($collection,"")}</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `util:unescape-uri()`, I would suggest using `xmldb:encode-uri()` and `xmldb:decode-uri()`.  Use the `encode` version on a collection or document name when creating/storing it.  Use the `decode` version when displaying the collection or document name.  See [the function documentation for the xmldb module](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/xmldb).

As to forcing `&auml;` instead of `ü`, this is an even trickier serialization issue.  Both, along with `&#228;`, are equivalent representations of the same UTF-8 character.  Why not just let the character through as `ü`?